# I will like to make Script that takes a computer name as a parameter

Tags: powershell

I want to write a PowerShell script that takes a computer name as a parameter and verifies that all service set to run automatically is running. If not, then these services should be started

- Make sure we get the status back
- If a service has stopped, can we get detailed information back about when it has stopped etc.
- Generate output to html (for example, on a default site so that it can be accessed on IIS)

any idea how I can do it best?

Comment: The best way is the way that works for your specific circumstance and solves your problem. What have you tried so far? Had a look at the `Get-Service`/`Start-Service`/`Stop-Service` cmdlets? Where exactly are you stuck? :)

Comment: more like when i can see then there a Auto startup or manuel started

Comment: `(Get-Service someServiceName).StartType`

Comment: yeah like that, but with all diffent services,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$global:resultRow=$null
$global:result=$null
$global:htmlTemplate=$null
$global:table_content=$null

function HtmlTable
{
     [OutputType([System.Object])]

    Param (
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]]
        $tableRows,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]] 
        $tableHeaders,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
        $tableWidthPercentage
    )        
    $htmTable = "<html>
                <style>
                body {font-family:Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;font-size:12px;}
                table{width: $tableWidthPercentage;border-collapse: collapse;}
                th{background-color:#106ebe; color:white;font-family:Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;font-size:12px;border: 1px solid black;padding: 4px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid #ddd;}
                tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
                td{font-family:Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;font-size:12px;border: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 4px;}
                </style>
                <table>
                <tr>"
    Foreach ($header in $tableHeaders)
    {
        $htmTable +=  "<th>$header</th>"
    }
   
    $htmTable +="</tr>
                $tableRows
                </table>"
    return $htmTable
}

function get-serviceStatus{
Param (
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String[]]
        $computerName
        
      )

$serviceList = get-service

foreach($service in $serviceList){

    if($service.StartType -contains 'Automatic' -and $service.status -ne 'Running' ){


                $resultRow = "
                <tr>
                <td>$service.Name</td>
                <td>$service.DisplayName</td>
                <td>$service.StartType</td>  
                <td>$service.Status</td>
                </tr>
                "
                $table_content += $resultRow
    
    }
    
  }
 $htmlTemplate= HtmlTable -tableWidthPercentage 80% -tableRows $table_content  -tableHeaders Name,DisplayName,Title,StartType,status
        return $htmlTemplate   
}




$result = get-serviceStatus -computerName <Replace with ComputerName>

$result| Out-File service.htm
```

Comment: if it helps you, please mark it as answer

Comment: So all that input i come with after are service there was stopped but started, ?  but how about to export it  to HTML files

Comment: @PeterSkovbjergPaulsen, please check the updated code, One function is to display the content in HTML format and other function is to get the status of service